# Opening Excel file keeps prompting "Read Only"

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I want to open existing file in my C# application excel file (xls) and write to specific columns all fine, but every time i open file its says only for reading, any idea how i save to it?

here is my current code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

string myPath = txtPath.Text.ToString();

excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);

excelApp.Cells[8, 3] = txtSum1.Text.ToString();
excelApp.Cells[8, 4] = txtId1.Text.ToString();
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Need more info. Is this file saved on a network share perchance? Anywhere other than in `MyDocuments`? In Excel, click `Start`=>`Options`then `Security center`. In the settings, make sure the file's location is a trusted location. Does that help?

Comment: Its saved on C disk..So file location is probably not a problem

Comment: What if you simply open it in Excel by hand? Also read-only? Close Excel, check in TaskManager for an extra Excel process running, kill it if there is one. Try again.

Comment: Okay i found that there was like 10 excel processes in background it seems it alway opens a new one and not close... what should i do differently?

Comment: If this turns out to be the solution, I'll delete my answer after either OP or @LocEngineer post their solution.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is write to a excel file you should not be using the Interop classes, you should be using the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) provided by Microsoft. That is the library designed for reading and writing to and from all Microsoft Office document formats.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple workbooks are getting opened and it's not able to override the previous one. So close one instance and open next one, it should work.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 string myPath = txtPath.Text.ToString();

 excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false,  
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
 excelApp.Cells[8, 3] = txtSum1.Text.ToString();
 excelApp.Cells[8, 4] = txtId1.Text.ToString();

excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
excelApp.Workbooks.Close();
excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: How should i be doing this? I was checking and if i call excelApp.Workbooks.Close(); at the end, still same its still opening new instance.

Comment: Remove excelApp.Visible = true; and programmatically save and close workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

This line starts a new Excel process as soon as it is executed. Now if you debug and single step through your code and decide "Oh, hey, I gotta do something else here", then hit the stop button - your Excel app won't magically go away but stay open! And if you hit the stop button after this line

```
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);
```

Then your file will be locked by that process.

Do this instead:

```
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

var excelApp = (Excel.Application) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
if(excelApp==null)
  excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

This should help you keep it at least down to 1 Excel process running.

And

```
Excel.Workbook wb;
try
{
  wb = excelApp.Workbooks[System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myPath)];
}
catch
{
  wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);
}
```

Not exactly sure about the last part. I am not sure whether addressing a non-existent workbook by name will resturn an error or null. if it returns null, just check for `if(wb == null)` instead of the catch clause.

Good luck!

Comment: OP can also just `excelApp.Quit();` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: True, but the line `excelApp.Visible = true;` kinda made me believe he didn't want that. Still true of course.

Comment: Agreed, just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Hmm o i should delete my excelApp = new Microsoft.Office... and use the one you posted with var? I tryed but now is searching for instance and its not opened yet so it crashes (An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll)

Comment: Yes, my first three lines would replace that one line. Please update your posted code so I know what exactly you did.

Comment: Excel Interop is not the "correct" way to write to an Excel file in C#.

Comment: @Aron: what is so awfully wrong with that? And where is the constructivity in your comment?

Comment: @LocEngineer The OP should be using the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) provided by Microsoft, not the office interop. That is the library designed for reading and writing to and from all Microsoft Office document formats.

Comment: @Aron Thank you. What is so hard about writing that little info instead of just downvoting and grouching? Still nothing wrong with learning to Interop the proper way. If for this simple case the SDK is a better _option_ fine. Trying to help here.

Comment: @Aron: Ok, willing to stab a hornets' nest: you can also bend over backwards. Yes, The SDK is the way to go - on server applications, heavy duty ops etc. This is lightweight operations and - obviously - meant for single-place users who do have Excel installed. It will work for xls - which _your_ suggestion won't - and it can be translated to great parts from recorded macros. I've researched a bit and yes, in a great number of cases I'd agree. In such a case though I couldn't give less of a hoot.

Comment: @LocEngineer Completely and utterly disagree with you analysis re: heavy duty/light weight. Excel is much much more heavy weight than running a library. Further, there are more OpenXML wrappers around that I would like to count, which will make your development much simpler. Finally, you don't need to deal with the huge number of possible issues that can happen when interoping (there happens to be a modal dialog in Excel, the user closed Excel, Excel crashed without you knowing, you are running the wrong version of Excel, you closing the user's Excel and pissing him off etc etc).

Comment: @LocEngineer The exception to this of course is when you ACTUALLY WANT TO INTERACT WITH EXCEL. Which is the case with macros. It's clear you have never had to support this solution before.

Comment: @Aron: well, that depends on whether or not he wants to run Excel in the first place. Since HyperX obviously wants the user to work with the newly modified file this is exactly what happens here so your point becomes pretty moot. That being said: let's agree to disagree, as completely and utterly as you like and not turn this into a political debate.

Comment: excelApp.Quit(); did the trick for me, otherwise the EXCEL.EXE process stays running in the background and you have to end it by going to task manager => services.